# AudioStreamer setDelegate is giving warning and crashing there in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, audiostreamer

i am playing an audiostreamer using AudioStreamer class.

these three mothods are giving warnings that AudioStreamer may not respond to these methods
and carshing at this first method.

```
[streamer setDelegate:self];
        [streamer setDidUpdateMetaDataSelector:@selector(metaDataUpdated:)];
        [streamer setDidErrorSelector:@selector(streamError)]
```

can anybody help me out...

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exception are you seeing when your program crashes?  If it is a 'does not respond to selector' exception and you are getting warnings that the class does not respond to those methods, this is damning evidence that the class doesn't actually respond to those selectors.

What is this AudioStreamer class?  I found one here:

https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

and if that is the one you are referring to, it looks likes it does not respond to those selectors.

Maybe you could give us more information about what you are trying to do.

EDIT: It appears AudioStreamer used to respond to those selectors, but has changed since.  You might be referring to out-of-date sample code or documentation